# Changing max_execution_time in Zend Server Developer Edition 9

Tags: zend-server

I have a script that keeps on timing out. I need to change my max_execution_time setting but can't seem to find it anywhere in Zend Server 9 Developer Edition. 
The documentation says it's easy to change under the "configurations" menu, but i can't see one anywhere and am going nuts.

http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Server-9/content/configuring%20php%20timeouts%20under%20windows%20apache.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to [http://server:10081/ZendServer/#!/php/extensions?grid=Resource Limits and Tuning](http://server:10081/ZendServer/#!/php/extensions?grid=Resource%20Limits%20and%20Tuning)

Change what you need, save and restart.